# Differential Equation $(1+x^2)y'-2xy=\cot(x)$ after integrating factor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$(1+x^2)y'-2xy=\cot(x)$$
or $$y'=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}y+\frac{\cot(x)}{1+x^2}$$

if I use an integrating factor $(e^{\int\frac{-2x}{1+x^2}dx}=\frac{1}{1+x^2})$ I get
$$\frac{y}{(1+x^2)}=\int\frac{\cot x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$ which I have no idea how to solve.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: what you have is right. the integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. that is all.

Comment: Well except what is front of the $y$.

Comment: Should be $\frac{1}{1+x^2}y=\int\frac{\cot x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Comment: Unless, of course, there's a $+$ on the LHS, in which case the equation is easy to solve.

Comment: You have arrived and are done.